# Rails model custom validation having one type of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a model User which have `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations.

app/models/user.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :advisors, dependent: :destroy
has_and_belongs_to_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
```

I want that either user have advisors association or either have teams . So want to add validation onn model level but can’t understand what have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom validation method https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

```rb
  validate :only_one_association_type

  private
  def only_one_association_type
    errors.add(:base, "can't have both types of associations") if advisors.any? && teams.any?
  end
```

That will add an error to the object if both advisors and teams are present.